# How do slice and print the mainline with the python-chess library?

Tags: python, chess, python-chess

There's a way to slice the mainline like we slice lists on Python? For example:

- mainline[start:stop]  # moves start through stop-1
- mainline[start:]      # moves start through the rest of the mainline
- mainline[:stop]       # moves from the beginning through stop-1

or

- mainline[start:stop:step] # start through not past stop, by step.

The idea is, having the `main_sicilian` object:

```
1. e4 c5 2. b4 cxb4 3. d4 d5 4. e5 Nc6 5. a3 Qb6 6. Ne2 Bf5 7. axb4 Nxb4 8. Na3 Rc8 9. Nf4 Bxc2 10. Qg4 e6 *
```

I would like to have:

```
main_sicilian[1:5] = 1. e4 c5 2. b4 cxb4 3. d4 d5 4. e5 Nc6 5. a3 Qb6
```

Also, by defining where it would finish. For example, until white's 3rd move:

```
1. e4 c5 2. b4 cxb4 3. d4
```

I tried the [documentation](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pgn.html) but I find it hard to use for a Python beginner.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. What have you tried? What did that give you? _"There's a way to slice the mainline..."_: are you asking us or telling us?

Comment: https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pgn.html#chess.pgn.GameNode.mainline `mainline()` _Returns an iterable over the mainline starting after this node._ Do you know what an iterable is, and how to convert it to a list? Once you do this, you can slice the list in the usual way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

##### code

```py
import io
import chess
import chess.pgn


pgn = io.StringIO("1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3 *")
game = chess.pgn.read_game(pgn)

var = []
for node in game.mainline():
    var.append(node.move)

# Slice up to 3 plies.
sliced_var = var[0:3]

# Convert to SAN format.
b = chess.Board()
san_sliced_var = b.variation_san(sliced_var)
print(san_sliced_var)
```

##### Output

`1. e4 c5 2. Nf3`

Comment: I'll accept it but doesn't do exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Could you explain more of what you are looking for?